# php json_encode array acess

Tags: php, json

i am tring to get a json request from query string id it almost works  but it is adding 
somesort of extra array object

```
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM ContactInfo WHERE id =' . $id );
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo json_encode($row);

{"0":"terry","FirstName":"terry","1":"rihoff","LastName":"rieff","2":"alientory","website":"alieory","3":"`123","PhoneNumber":"`123","4":"123","Fax":"123","5":"2","id":"2"}
```

i should only be getting one contact but looks like exrtra array being add to each field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` returns an array with numeric and string keys so you have the data twice (once with a numeric index and once with a string index).  Try:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Or:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: both those option worked great thanks i new it had to be something simple